# Samsung Tizen TV catch right click event

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I have some problem with catching right click event on my web app, tried to use `window.oncontextmenu`, but for some reasons unknown to me it is not work on Tizen. But when I debug my app via desctop browser, everything work as it should.

What I need to do to activate right click event handler on **Samsung TV Tizen**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in general I have lowered my expectations in regards to what will work with the browser running on Tizen displays.

Anyway, a few things that may help you:

Firstly there are oftentimes issues with privileges on Tizen, it's possible that is a problem for you. You can check the privileges available to you for any related to mouse input.

Also I was able to find:

```
<feature name="http://www.samsungdforum.com/feature/Mouse"/>
```

Sadly it seems no one really knows what this is or what it does, as the documentation is very poor.

Since you are testing using your device I suspect you have also tested left click. Presumably if that is working it is likely not a privilege issue. In this case I suggest trying a different approach, as I remember to have encountered trouble with events on SAMSUNG browsers as well in the past:

http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/guides/user-interaction/mouse

There is some info on setting up the onEvent callback properly.

Last but not least, instead of

```
window.oncontextmenu
```

try

```
document.oncontextmenu
```

Comment: I did all  you said but right click don't work yet while click work, any idea ?